# Swift Use of Unresolved Identifier 'GMServices'

Tags: google-maps-api-3, swift, xcode6

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  let googleMapsApiKey = "AIzaSyDc7eBtBwvAWucUaJcI6chyc9zNhbLQFao"

  func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {



    GMSservices.provideAPIKey(googleMapsApiKey)
    return true
  }

}
```

I'm having this reoccurring issue where the GMServices error keeps on appearing, yet I have all the relevant framework etc. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After you imported Google Maps iOS SDK, you need to have a bridge header defined, then the SDK will be recognized.

To create this bridge header, add an arbitrary Objective-C file(eg: a .m file) to your project. Xcode will prompt to ask you if to configure a bridge header for you.

Click Yes to continue.

A file ending with -Bridging-Header.h will be added to your project.

Simply add #import  in the bridge header, and you are good to go!

Also, it's safe to delete that temporary Objective-C file now.

For more Information refer this link : http://dubinski.org/wpis/google-maps-sdk-with-swift-tutorial/

Comment: I followed those exact steps, however it still doesn't give me the option to create a header file. so.. I just imported a header file from a similar project, is that alright?

Comment: from my opinion you should create new file with command + n-> iOS source->Header File and after that import #import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> into that file that may be work.

Comment: found the solution! In Xcode, if you go into the build settings for your target, and scroll all the way down you'll find a "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" section.

Set "Objective-C Bridging Header" to <#PROJECT_NAME>-Bridging-Header.h

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Add a temporary Objective-C file to your project. You may give it any name you like.

Select Yes to configure an Objective-C bridging header.

Delete the temporary Objective-C file you just created.

In the projectName-Bridging-Header.h file just created, add this line:

*'#import < GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h >'*

**Edit the AppDelegate.swift file:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIza....") //iOS API key

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me just recently when I updated my cocoapods. Now I see:

- `Using GoogleMaps (1.10.3)`
- `COCOAPODS: 0.39.0`

The import in the bridging header, `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` used to work.

Now, to resolve the issue, I had to add `import GoogleMaps` to the Swift file that has the error.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer really helped, just adding #import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> didn't work

Comment: @eilas, I'm glad this helped you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add these imports at the top of the file

import GoogleMaps

import GooglePlaces